# Separately continuous functions of the first Baire class

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

**Problem.** Let $X,Y$ be (completely regular) topological spaces such that every separately continuous functions $f:X^2\to\mathbb R$ and $g:Y^2\to \mathbb R$ are of the first Baire class. Is every separately continuous function $h:X\times Y\to\mathbb R$ of the first Baire class?

---

This problem was posed on 7 January 2022 by Volodymyr Mykhaylyuk on [page 114](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=114) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

**Prize.** 10 bottles of beer.